# How to choose a DNS server based on the FQDN of the thing being resolved?

Tags: macos, dns

So I'm running macOS Catalina, but also have a couple of Win10 VMs.

When plugged into the corporate WiFi I have to access a couple different domains.  Unfortunately we do not have a DNS server that responds to all these things.  And the fallbacks are all messed up.  I'm not the network admin.

Is there some way I can instruct my OS to select a DNS server based on the FQDN that is being resolved?

For instance, if DOMAIN-A dns server is on 10.250.1.1 and DOMAIN-B dns server is on 10.251.1.1... then when I try to resolve host.domain-a.local it should use 10.250.1.1 to resolve it, and differenthost.domain-b.local should use 10.251.1.1.

If the solution also allows me to apply some translation rules that would be awesome.  For instance, domain-b resolves hosts in the 10.60.c.d range.. but due to network architecture that has to be translated into 10.90.c.d addresses.  That would be icing, but not required.

Comment: Create an /etc/resolver directory, and put files in it named for the domains you want special handling for. See [`man 5 resolver`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/5/resolver/), this [Mac OS X Hints page](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2004062902195410), and [several previous Q&As](https://superuser.com/search?q=%2Fetc%2Fresolver). Note that this only works with things that use the system resolver; `dig`, `host`, `nslookup`, and AIUI Chrome and Firefox all do their own name resolution, and won't obey resolver files.

Comment: I don't know is this feasible for you, but you could create your own DNS server(MS Nano server is a good way to go) with stub zones, or conditional forwarders and make it a default(first to look) DNS server for your maschines. Your own DNS server could help you with the last part of your question (_"translation rules"_)

Comment: DNSMasq with server=/domain.name/DNS.IP.add.res directives.